# NSMutableURLRequest adding extra information to the body, making Content-Length incorrect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, http, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using an NSMutableURLRequest to perform a simple file upload from iOS5 to a custom server. When I send the request, I have it print out the length of bodyContents, which contains the body of the request. For the particular request I am working on, it will say that the length is 46784. I don't set the content-length, since I found out it was doing that automatically, but I pull the info anyway in case I need it later. The headers being received by the server say that the content-length is 46784. When I do a character count on the body at the server end, it tells me that the length of the body is 46788, 4 too many. I ran another request, again, the request had 4 more characters than what I sent.

At first, I thought it had to be on the server side, just because it didn't make any sense. So I sent a request from a test program that I know works to the server, and checked the length of the body it sent against the content-length header and they were identical.

What is the best way to deal with this? Should I manually set the content-length to `4+[bodyContents length]`? I don't think that would be what I would want to do, just because I shouldn't have to add extra space for data I don't know that I want.

Here is the code that sends the request

```
-(void)send:(id)delegate
{
    bodyContents = [bodyContents stringByAppendingFormat:@"--%@--",boundry];
    NSInteger length = [bodyContents length];
    NSLog(@"Length is %i",length);
    [request setHTTPBody:[bodyContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
    if(connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection good");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection bad");
    }
}
```

I set the content-type property of the request in the init method of the class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify an encoding, the size of the contents can change... get the size ***after*** you set the HTTPBody and then see if that adjusts things up by four bytes automatically.

Comment: I just tried that, it gives me the same length both before and after the encoding and the length of the body is still 4 characters longer than what it should be.

Comment: Next thing to do would be to `diff` the bytes between what you send and what's received and see what the difference is.

Comment: I ran a diff and found no differences in the requests, but that got me to thinking, why not run a diff on the working request and the non working request (something I should have done a long time ago) and it pointed out 2 or 3 little changes I needed to make. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I was able to guide you to the solution!  And I hope your question will help other people down the road.